# Why is my Saga blocking access to the event handlers?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I am trying to attempt a Saga in NServiceBus. I have the following:

```
public class MyProcessor: Saga<MySaga>, IAmStartedByMessages<MyMessage1>,
    IAmStartedByMessages<MyMessage2>, IHandleTimeouts<MyTimeout>

protected override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga(SagaPropertyMapper<MySaga> mapper) {
    mapper.ConfigureMapping<MyMessage1>(m => m.Id).ToSaga(s => s.Id);
    mapper.ConfigureMapping<MyMessage2>(m => m.Id).ToSaga(s => s.Id);
}

public void Handle(MyMessage1 message) {
    // logic
    RequestTimeout<MyTimeout>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
}

public void Handle(MyMessage2 message) {
    // logic
    MarkAsComplete();
}

public void Timeout(MyTimeout state) {
    // logic
    MarkAsComplete();
}
```

So the architecture is such that `Message1` is expected to come in first, but after some timeout, we give up on waiting for `Message2`. However if `Message2` does come in after the timeout, it's still ok, ergo both of these are marked as `IAmStartedByMessages`. Now the problem is this: if I am publishing `Message2`, the code runs, the saga is complete, and I can continue publishing more events. However, if I run `Message1` handler first, it blocks this entire Processor, I can no longer publish neither `Message1` nor `Message2`. What is a reason such a block could occur?

I am using `InMemoryPersistence` for development.

Comment: There's too little information provided. What is the value of message.Id for new messages? If message.Id for new messages is the same as in the one that started the saga, the saga will swallow them. Also, there is a flaw in your saga logic when you first send Message1 and then Message2 with the same Id. Since saga with this Id already exists, Message2 handler will not be called.

Comment: I answered the question below, though I am curious what you mean when you say that if Message1 then Message2, then Message2's handler will not be called? It seems to be working as desired, but I am curious if I am missing an edge case or something.

Comment: I might be wrong about this but your saga can be started by both Message1 and Message2. If you saga is identified by some Id and your saga has been started by Message1 with, for example, id = 10, the saga data will be available with id = 10. When Message2 comes with the same id and your saga class is configured to start a new saga on Message2, it should check if a saga with the same id already exists and do not start a new saga if it does. However, it might be that in such case IAmStartedByMessage is identical to IHandleMessage, I have never tried this.

Comment: What I would have done in such case is to have a separate handler for Message2 and from that handler send a message to finish the saga. Remember, that it is strongly _not_ recommended to have any business logic inside saga handlers. Instead, saga behaves as process manager and sends other messages, whose handlers perform the logic and reply to the saga with status updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not realize that the `Data` relevant to the configure needed to be set within the `Handler`. I thought that was automatically handled by `ConfigureHowToFindSaga`. So within my `Message1` handler, all I needed was the following code:

```
Data.Id = message.Id;
```

In this way, the sage is created with appropriate Id set, and then the next time we access it, it actually exists.